# How to diff two commits (patches) to the same change in Gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

I have two patches to the same commit in `Gerrit`.  The first was made explicitly as a patch (amendment) to the change but the second one came from another change that was built on top of that change and got approved and merged before this change.  So I need to produce a diff between the two patches.  What makes it more difficult is that they were actually pushed from two different local `git` branches (I have a habit of forking a new branch for each commit I'll be sending to Gerrit).

So my question is:  how to diff two commits (patches) to the same change in Gerrit?

Comment: so the second patch was submitted to the remote branch?

Comment: yes but to another commit that has the same parent so it patched this one automatically.

Answer (score 7):

It is easy. If you want to show diffs between patchsets just go to "Files" section and look for "Diff against:" - see red box in the image-. It will show you the differences between your current patchset against the patchset you select in the combo - see the blue box -
[image]

If you need to compare between different old patchsets, just go to "Patch Sets" (usually at the right top corner of the screen), select one of the old patchsets and then repeat the process with "Diff against".

Answer (score 6):

In the diff screen, select a different version instead of `Base` in the `Patch Set` selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
git review -m <CHANGE_NUMBER>,<OLD_PS>[-<NEW_PS>]
```

But git review AFAIK above git version 1.25.x.x.

Comment: this is the much more useful answer, the GUI is obvious but how to do it on CLI to get a patchfile is not.

Answer (score -1):

first fetch the submitted change (`git fetch`) then [checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19778924/1342413) the first change, then use `git diff origin/<branch>` where the submitted commit was merged