# Gerrit cherry pick

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a problem, when I cherry pick a commit from gerrit, make changes etc. And I want to commit them back with --amend to my commit before that cherrypick how could I do that?
Right now I have just add -A all files, however I have no idea what to do next

Comment: Do you actually mean review/change instead of "commit from gerrit" and fetch/checkout instead of cherry-pick?

Comment: the cherry pick commit is a patchset from Gerrit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amending is possible only for the latest commit. Let's assume that the commit you wand to amend is called (has a SHA-1 code) `111`. You can see the real SHA-1 code of your commit in `git log`.

You can use `git reset --hard` to make your local branch point to the commit you want to amend. Note that with "plain" git without Gerrit it would be a very bad idea as you are rewriting history by modifying already pushed commit!

I assume that you already have local, uncommitted changes to some files and you want to apply these changes to the commit `111`. You have to stash these changes, because `git reset --hard` [will remove them and it couldn't be undone](http://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html).

So you have to do (replace `master` with the name of a branch you're on):

```
git stash save
git reset --hard 111
git stash apply
<do some more changes to commit 111 if needed>
git commit --amend
git push gerrit master:refs/for/master
```

And voila - your commit 111 was amended and updated with Gerrit.

There is another way to do that - you can use `git rebase --interactive`, but I find it more complicated than `git reset` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The Gerrit-workflow in your case is:

- Fetch a change from Gerrit using URL from the review page
- Making changes
- Add changes to the index with `git add -A .`
- Amend previous commit with `git commit --amend`
- Push amended commit back to the Gerrit `git push gerrit master:refs/for/master` (replace `master` with your and remote branch names)

Comment: I have made some changes commited them, then I cherryPicked other commit, made another changes and now I want them to be pushed on the first commit right before my cherrypick, now when I am doing amend Im on that cherry picked commit unfortunately

Comment: you can do it with interactive rebase (`git rebase -i HEAD~3`). Then replace `pick` by `e` in front of the commit you want to amend. After you done with amending, issue `git rebase --continue` to finish the operation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19778924/1342413) instead of cherry pick a change/patchset from Gerrit. Whit checkout the commits wont depends. In your case amending the last modification will affect on the last commit, which is the cherry pick - that is normal. But if you would like to amend the change on the 1. commit, then just delete the cherry pick commmit first.